# Hashtable is empty when I want to access it in a private class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashtable, keylistener

As in the title, I have a hashtable which contains  and which is initialized with few commands like ("Copy",new Copy()) for example

I have this function which initialize the hashtable :

```
    public void setCommands(Hashtable<String, Command> h){
    this.commands = h;
    this.commands.get("write").execute();
}
```

And a private which contains my keylistener. To explain the process, when I press a key it call a methode execute() from my command which enter a key in a buffer. The latter one is displayed in my user interface.

Here is my private class for my keylistener :

```
private class KeyListener implements java.awt.event.KeyListener
{   
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyChar())
        {
        case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE :
            commands.get("delete").execute();
            break;
        default : 
            lastChar = String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
            commands.get("write").execute();
            break;  
        }   
    }
}
```

So, when I run my app and press a Key I have a NullPointerExpection at the line "command.get("write").execute() whereas my hashtable is not empty !!

Here is the stackTrace if you want :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at invoker.UserInterface$KeyListener.keyPressed(UserInterface.java:149)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I would be very thankful if someone could give me some advices about this problem, I'm stuck on this **** since hours :(
Thanks

Comment: try to sysout what's in the commands table before calling the command.

Comment: it returns null I didn't point it out

Comment: So `System.out.println(commands)` gives null? It might help if you posted more of the code, or put it on pastebin. A lot of important stuff is not shown here.

Comment: So, if your `HashTable` is not empty, what is in it? Does the key "write" exist? Did you debug it, or did you print out all the contents?

Comment: Here is my git repository if you want to check the whole code (If you have any questions feel free to ask, i think it's easier for you to check the whole code than if I give you parts of code): https://bitbucket.org/t3x4s/java/src

Comment: The hashtable returns the correct keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your user interface twice, but only one of the two instances get the `commands` `Hashtable`!

The first user interface object is created here in main.java:

```
UI = new UserInterface();
```

The second one in the line after the next line:

```
IHMObserver ihm = new IHMObserver(editor);
```

`IHMObserver` is a subclass of `UserInterface`, so when it's constructed, a second window opens in front of the first. But you only set your commands to the `UI` instance, not to `ihm`. But as the second window is shown in front of the first one, it will catch the key- and mouse-events and as `commands` is `null` there, an exception occures.

The solution is simple: Just skip the first line (`new UserInterface()`) and set the commands to the `ihm` object instead:

```
editor = new EditorEngine();
IHMObserver ihm = new IHMObserver(editor);

// commands creation comes here

ihm.setCommands(commands);
editor.registerObserver(ihm);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really, I was totally lost in this mess !